# Different output across browser for Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

Below is what I have in **Javascript**

```
var x=["1","2","3","4","5","6"];
c = (b = x[1])[0] ;
alert("B=" + b);
alert("C=" + c);
```

When I run this in Firefox 9.0.1, I get below output.

```
B=2
C=2
```

When I run *same* in IE7, I get below output.

```
B=2
C=undefined
```

Can I know why **IE** is displaying as **undefined**??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because IE7 doesn't support accessing strings by index.

This works in all browsers:

```
c = (b = x[1]).charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because Internet Explorer does not support the [array-like character access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) for Strings.

In your code, you want to access the first character of the following String: `"2"` which is not supported in Internet Explorer.

You can use [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to achieve the same results:

```
c = (b = x[1]).charAt(0);
```